# How to tell if a HTML table has an empty cell (&nbsp) using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Here is the HTML I'm trying to parse. I want to use everything that actually has information and not just &nbsp, but for some reason I can't seem to check if the info in those columns are empty.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td class=""><a href="/website.com">Cal83</a></td>
     <td class="">List </td>
     <td>07/19/12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the code I'm using to try to parse it. It can get it just fine until it gets to the &nbsp line. I'm trying to make sure the line has something in it besides whitespace or an empty string.

```
    Elements rows = calendarPage.getElementsByTag("tr");
        for (Element row : rows) {
            Elements td = row.getElementsByTag("td");
            if (td.get(0).hasText()){      //&nbsp
                System.out.println(td.get(0).text());
                Element link = td.get(0).select("a").first();
            }
        }
```

I tried using .hasText() like I showed there, checking if it's whitespace, an empty string, null, and I even tried checking if it was \u\&nbsp. But it never gets caught, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this implement with selector:

```
 Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
 Elements rows = table.select("tr");
 for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) { 
    Element row = rows.get(i);
    Elements cols = row.select("td");

    System.out.println(cols.get(i).text().equals("\u00a0")); // to check "&nbsp:"
}
```

However when parsing text node, and this conatins `&nbsp;` entity it is converted by calling `.text()` on this element to `#160 ASCII` char.
A non-breaking space is not the same as a normal space. Non breaking space is `0xA0` or `160 decimal` in `ISO-8859-*`, `Windows-1252`, it is `U+00A0` in Unicode (in `UTF-8` it is encoded to `0xC2 0xA0`). So its depend on your character encoding.